# PHP Header & CSV WITH NO download option

Tags: php, csv, header

I have written a script using header function that generates CSV file.Let me explain in detail.
Step 1) I am saving records in mysql.Step 2) I am creating CSV file from saved records from database Step 3) I want to attach that CSV in attachments so that i could send it to different recipents!! I have completed the two steps.But i dont want download functionality in CSV file generation process as i dont want this file available to anyone. My code looks like this:

```
        $file_name = "Register_" . date('l');

        $file_name.=".csv";

      header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name");
        header("Pragma: no-cache");

        header("Expires: 0");
        print "$header\n$data";
```

Where do I need to make changes?

Answer (score 0):

just remove all calls to `header()` and the last `print`

Answer (score 0):

You could do what you try to by using the ob_buffer functions and 'catching' the generated output. However the whole approach is a little strange:

the header functions have nothing to do with creating emails. They serve the purpose to specify how a browser should handle transferred data. 'Cause this is what you do: you send headers and data. Don't.

Instead: write the csv data into a buffer or file and create an email using one of the available email classes (google...). Then take that crafted email and send it. No header() function required for that.

Comment: Let me clarify here.I am using "phpmailer class" for sending attachments.Let me explain this in details: Step 1) I am saving records in mysql.Step 2) I am creating CSV file from saved records from database Step 3) I want to attach that CSV in attachments so that i could send it to different recipents!! I have completed the two steps.But i dont want download functionality in CSV file generation process as i dont want this file available to anyone.Thanks

Comment: Well that would have been some vital information. Why did you keep it from people you ask for help? Apart from that: I still have the impression there is a deep missunderstanding on your side: what do you mean by "attach that CSV in attachments". Attach to what? You SEND it. So this is what is happening. Why do you specify headers and send it when you don't want to send it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AddStringAttachment`:

```
$file_name = "Register_" . date('l') . ".csv";
$excelContent = "$header\n$data";
$phpmailer->AddStringAttachment($excelContent, $file_name, 'base64', 'application/vnd.ms-excel');
```